# How to p4 obliterate changelist history

Tags: perforce

I've obliterated some changelists from p4, but now they leave empty entries saying that "changelist contains no files, yada-yada". How can I delete these entries from perforce database?

Answer (score 2):

"p4 change -d -f CHANGE" will allow you (as an admin) to delete an empty submitted changelist.